# When Vue router navigate to /login and give an error when the backend fails to resolve the token

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When using the vue router, when the backend fails to resolve the token, the front-end route navigates to /login, and the following error occurs (Navigation cancelled from "/home" to "/login" with a new navigation.) Even weirder, the same scenario does not occur when i use  browser to debug, and the following error occurs when the page is refreshed directly
[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVkVs.png)

vue router config

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    //  ====== 登录  =====
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: () => import('@/views/login/Login.vue'),
    },
    //  ====== 主页  =====
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Layout',
        component: Layout,
        redirect: '/home',
        children: [  // 子路由
            {
                path: 'home',
                name: 'Home',
                component: () => import('@/views/home/HomeView.vue'),
            },
            //  ====  User  ====
            {
                path: 'userList',
                name: 'UserList',
                component: () => import('@/views/user/User.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'addUser',
                name: 'AddUser',
                component: () => import('@/views/user/AddUser.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'editUser',
                name: 'EditUser',
                component: () => import('@/views/user/EditUser.vue'),
            },
            //  ====  Admin  ====
            {
                path: 'adminList',
                name: 'AdminList',
                component: () => import('@/views/admin/List.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'addAdmin',
                name: 'AddAdmin',
                component: () => import('@/views/admin/Add.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'editAdmin',
                name: 'EditAdmin',
                component: () => import('@/views/admin/Edit.vue'),
            },
            //  ====  Category  ====
            {path: 'categoryList', name: 'CategoryList', component: () => import('@/views/category/List.vue')},
            {path: 'addCategory', name: 'AddCategory', component: () => import('@/views/category/Add.vue')},
            {path: 'editCategory', name: 'EditCategory', component: () => import('@/views/category/Edit.vue')},
            //  ====  Book  ====
            {path: 'bookList', name: 'BookList', component: () => import('@/views/book/List.vue')},
            {path: 'addBook', name: 'AddBook', component: () => import('@/views/book/Add.vue')},
            {path: 'editBook', name: 'EditBook', component: () => import('@/views/book/Edit.vue')},
            //  ====  Borrow  ====
            {path: 'borrowList', name: 'BorrowList', component: () => import('@/views/borrow/List.vue')},
            {path: 'addBorrow', name: 'AddBorrow', component: () => import('@/views/borrow/Add.vue')},
            {path: 'editBorrow', name: 'EditBorrow', component: () => import('@/views/borrow/Edit.vue')},
            //  ====  Return  ====
            {path: 'returList', name: 'returList', component: () => import('@/views/retur/List.vue')},
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "*",
        component: () => import('@/views/404')
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'hash',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})
//TODO 有问题
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN)
    if (token) {
        if (to.path === '/login') {
            return next({path: '/'})
        } else {
            next()
        }
    } else {
        if (to.path === '/login') {
            next()
        } else {
            next({path: 'login', query: {redirect: to.path}})
        }
    }
})


export default router
```

response interceptors config

```
request.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        const {code, description} = response.data
        let res = response.data;
        // 兼容服务端返回的字符串数据
        if (typeof res === 'string') {
            res = res ? JSON.parse(res) : res
        }
        //以403开头的错误码均为token不存在、失效、解析异常等错误
        //the response code start with 403 means token nonexistent, invalid, parsing exception, etc
        if (code.toString().startsWith("403")) {
            localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN)
            Notification.error(description)
            router.push('/login')
        }
        return res;
    },
    error => {
        console.log('err' + error) // for debug
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
)
```

The expected result should be that when the backend fails to resolve the token, the vue router should jump to the /login with no error

Comment: Try changing the `redirect: "/home"` to `redirect: "/login"`